# What's wrong with my bitmap? How to get pixel data of what I drew?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, bitmap

Here's my buffer for an animation:

```
Bitmap PixBuffer;
```

Here's how I create it:

```
PixBuffer = new Bitmap(ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Here's how I draw on it:

```
Graphics Renderer { get { return Graphics.FromImage(PixBuffer); } }
```

To make long story short. It works. I draw. I see changes. I use the bitmap as `BackgroundImage` for a window. Since the window has `DoubleBuffered` = `true`, it's silky smooth and fast.

OK, and the WTF part. I try to clone a slice of my bitmap, or even whole thing:

```
PixBuffer = (Bitmap)PixBuffer.Clone();
```

It doesn't make much sense, it should do nothing with what's displayed. But guess what - the clone is EMPTY! Exactly the same result if I try to draw `PixBuffer` on a new bitmap. The contents of PixBuffer is displayed. It can be even stretched as windows background. But I see no way to copy it. `RotateFlip` has no effect too.

What am I doing wrong? How to get pixel data of what I drew?

```
                Freeze = (Bitmap)PixBuffer.Clone();
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Freeze)) {
                    g.FillRectangle(BrushF, 0, 0, 100, 100);
                    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                    g.Dispose();
                }
                var test = (Bitmap)Freeze.Clone();
                BackgroundImage = test;
```

When I set `PixBuffer` as `BackgroundImage` - I get my drawn image. When I set `Freeze` as `BackgroundImage` - I get a square.

Then, if I clone `Freeze` to let's say `Freeze1` - I still get my square, so cloning actually works on some bitmaps. But on PixBuffer NO JOY!

PixBuffer is not drawn in one frame. It is drawn as progressing animation during ca 30s. After animation completes - I have still screen - this screen I want to have as a normal bitmap to manipulate (like scaling and such). It seems like PixBuffer is write-only. I can still draw on it, but I can't copy anything from it.

I even tried to convert it to `Icon` and then back to `Bitmap` - but it's exactly the same like I was doing operations on empty `Bitmap` object.

But it IS NOT EMPTY! I tested it. I removed the `BackgroundImage`. I set another image in its place. And then I set `PixBuffer` as `BacgroundImage` again - and it is not empty, there is all I drew.

I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you try `Bitmap PixBuffer2 = (Bitmap)PixBuffer.Clone();`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. Doesn't work. PixBuffer2 is empty.

Comment: instead of PixBuffer = (Bitmap)PixBuffer.Clone(); try  PixBuffer = new Bitmap(PixBuffer);

Comment: No joy. Tried this. Empty bitmap.

Comment: `Bitmap PixBuffer2 = PixBuffer.Clone();` should work. Your original code of `PixBuffer = (Bitmap)PixBuffer.Clone();` throws an OOM exception There must be something else happening. Have you put it inside a try clause and hide the exception?

Comment: as TaW suggested pixbuffer2 will be empty right? also look at that moment to pixbuffer to see if its also  empty.

Comment: You should post more of your relevant code - it might be some side effect you omitted here, because you are not aware of (like variable scoping or something).
Also, try to construct a minimal example of what you're doing. Chances are that you will find the bug this way. Oh, and please stick to the C# naming convention.

Comment: If i was to guess(as i can only do that with the code presented)i would guess you somewhere in your code are assigning a new bitmap to pixbuffer(completly erasing the previous content).

Comment: OK! I got it. It IS empty. I have no idea how I could display it then...

Comment: then...problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thanks. You were right. I cleared the bitmap myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of those very nasty bugs in code.

```
    void RenderFrame(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var r = Graphics.FromImage(PixBuffer)) r.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        var end = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < Speed; i++) if (end = !UnmaskOne()) break;
        RenderText();
        RenderPattern();
        if (end) FreezeContent = true;
        Refresh();
    }
```

I tried to copy my bitmap in `UnmaskOne()` method, which is called directly after clearing the frame, since this method can detect, if there's nothing more to unmask. However I had to wait with copying the bitmap - it should be drawn first with `RenderText()` and `RenderPattern()` methods. No magic here. Just plain human error.

Comment: And now I understand how I could DISPLAY an EMPTY image! I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with `Interval` 1. On a double buffered window it updates the content at 60FPS without flickering. If I assign empty `PixBuffer` to `BackgroundImage` - it appears because it's drawn BEFORE system refreshes the screen. BTW, I just discovered a really fast drawing method for ultra-slow WinForms :) Like how much `DrawString / Clear / DrawString` is faster than `Label.Location=...`? Way faster. And WinForms keeps timing and blanking as good as WPF.